# XAML UWP Windows Store : error CS0266/warning CS1697 when deploying solution

Tags: xaml, uwp

I've some warning/error when trying to "create App Packages" from a XAML UWP project.

Firstly a warning :

```
2017\Projects\MyProjectName\MyProjectName\obj\x86\Release\MyPageName.g.cs(1,1,1,194): warning CS1697: Different checksum values given for C:\Users\administrateur\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MyProjectName\MyProjectName\MyPageName.xaml
```

It seem there is a problem with space (the second path is beginning after the last space -before "2017"-). I'm on Win 10.

Ive an cast error too :

```
1>C:\Users\administrateur\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MyProjectName\MyProjectName\obj\x86\Release\MyPageName.g.cs(39,36,39,85): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button' to 'MyProjectName.MyButtonReturn'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

`MyButtonReturn` is a button coded in a class extending Button, the definition of "MyButtonReturn" is :

```
 public sealed class MyButtonReturn : Button
  {...
```

Any help ? 
Thanks

Comment: Show some codes xaml and c# else will not able to help and 2 error may be correct by cleaning your solution

Comment: How do you use your custom button?

Comment: xmlns:local="using:MyProjectName" and <local:MyButtonReturn ... /> on XAML. I use it as a normal button in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, cleaning the solution + building the project on release worked.